# Tinymce 5.1.0 version not working with react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Trying to use tinymce with react, but the latest version of @tinymce/tinymce-react is 4.3.0. I want to use the 5.1.0 version how i can do that in react? Any help? with setting up codeas tinymce.init is not  working

Can't use the Tinymce with React

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `@tinymce/tinymce-react` version is decoupled from the `tinymce` version it uses. The 4.x.x version of `@tinymce/tinymce-react` will display TinyMCE 4, 5 or 6, though it will default to 6 when it has to load the editor itself from the cloud.

If you are using the cloud version then the easiest way to set the TinyMCE version by setting the [`cloudChannel`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#cloudchannel) property. Note that you should also be setting the [`apiKey`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#apikey) property when loading from the cloud.

Alternatively if you are loading the editor from a local source then you can either include a script tag linking to the editor or set the [`tinymceScriptSrc`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#tinymcescriptsrc).

You can read more about loading the editor in the official documentation:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-ref/#configuring-editor-source